# Compile error in wxWidgets with VS2010 Beta 2

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, wxwidgets, compilation

i try to build wxWidgets straight from source using VS10 beta 2, but i get this error when i try to compile it:

```
Error   1   error MSB3073: The command "copy "" ..\..\lib\vc_lib\mswd\wx\setup.h
:VCEnd" exited with code 1. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cp\\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets   145
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix that particular error by creating folders in:

/lib/vc_lib
 or 
/lib/vc_dll

The folders were

msw/wx

mswd/wx

mswu/wx

mswud/wx

.. etc according to the configuration that was being built

I was able to build the lib versions:

Stable Release: 2.8.10 - had to open the /build/msw/wx.dsw in VC 2008 and then in VC 2010 for the project conversion to work.A bit of work setting up the build order, the above folders in /lib and it compiles. Did not attempt building samples.

Development Snapshot: 2.9.0 - a lot easier. It comes with VC 2008 solution files and can be loaded in VC 2010. Set up the folder in the lib output folders and it compiles. Built the /samples/menu project (static lib Debug & Release) without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you use svn checkout you need to ensure that the file include/wx/msw/setup.h exists (and not just setup0.h, just copy setup0.h to setup.h if you don't need to edit it). Otherwise check the project settings as they might have been not imported correctly -- the empty file name in copy command is very suspicious, it should be "....\include\wx\msw\setup.h" normally.

FWIW I checked that the build with VC10 beta2 works just yesterday but I had to do this change (http://svn.wxwidgets.org/viewvc/wx?view=revision&revision=62567) in order to get rid of the warnings about unknown compiler version. IOW you should use an svn checkout or apply this patch locally.